# Transpose multi column data into single row using python from HTML

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, beautifulsoup

i am trying to transpose a HTML retrieved code by beautiful soup. The website was having 2 HTML tables in it . i have taken the tables into a variable.

```
  table = pd.read_html(page)
  table1 =  table[0]    
  table2 =  table[1]
```

The output of table1 and table2 combined gives :

```
    0  1
0   a  A         
1   b  B
2   c  C
3   d  D
4   e  E
5   f  F
6   g  G
```

The  0 and 1 in starting row and column are auto generated by pandas while i have used

```
 table = pd.read_html(url)
```

I want to reshape the table 1 and table 2 in a such way that

```
table = ['a','A','b','B','c','C','d','D','e','E','f','F','g','G']
```

I have other list

```
 Second_list = ['AA','BB','CC','DD','EE']
```

table dataframe should be matching with second_list so that both can be combined

```
table = table + Second_list
```

so that output of table would be

```
['a','A','b','B','c','C','d','D','e','E','f','F','g','G','AA','BB','CC','DD','EE']
```

any solution other than above approach is much appreciated, the goal was to remove the auto generated columns and rows by pandas and make the multicolumn data into single row

Thanks a lot in advance, have a great day

Comment: `df.values.flatten()` ??

Comment: it was showing the same  structure, thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to flatten the dataframe, you can use `np.ravel`. For example:

```py
Second_list = ["AA", "BB", "CC", "DD", "EE"]
x = df.values.ravel().tolist() + Second_list
print(x)
```

Prints:

```
['a', 'A', 'b', 'B', 'c', 'C', 'd', 'D', 'e', 'E', 'f', 'F', 'g', 'G', 'AA', 'BB', 'CC', 'DD', 'EE']
```

Comment: Thanks a lot , it is working like charm :) .is ravel() function is used to remove the auto generated rows and columns in pandas?